# Calculating Mash Water Volume When Brewing with Pumpkin

Tags: pumpkin, fruit, mash-volume, sparge

Okay, so pumpkins are not in season and I'm substituting winter squash (acorn/butternut) for my pumpkin ale recipe, but the concept remains the same as if it were pumpkin.  I've never brewed with pumpkin (or any other fruits/vegetables for that matter), so I have some questions.

The grain bill is 13.75 lbs.  If I weren't using pumpkin I would use 1.25 quarts of mash water per pound of grain, equaling 4.3 gallons.

My questions is, if I'm adding about 8 pounds of pumpkin, do I need to increase my mash volume to account for that, and if so, by how much?

Since the pumpkin will be saturated with water, I know I don't need to account for absorption in the same way that I do with the grains, but is the water displaced by the pumpkin enough to keep the grains fully submerged?  Do I need more sparge water?

Comment: I think you meant to say 1.25 *quarts* of water per pound

Comment: FYI Google tells me that (boiled) pumpkin is about 6% carbohydrates (1% protein, and not much else other than water) Barley is about 73%. Make what you will with that.
Edit: My maths says that your normal mash is about 20% carbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I brew a sweet potato beer and I assume 1qt/lb of sweet potato.  I also adjust the thickness by eye after that.  The water to grist/veg ratio isn't really all that critical.  Nor is it all that different if you have to adjust the water a little up pr down by 10-15%.

The key is to have enough water in there that it doesn't become a gooped up mess.  The mash needs to be liquid enough to lauter.  This is where mash experience just comes into play.  Its more of a feel issue than a set #.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!  I was starting to wonder if I would get an answer in time for tomorrow.  I've never done anything like this so I appreciate hearing from someone who has.

I was reading that sweet potatoes can make really interesting beer.  I'll have to try that sometime.  Cheers!

Comment: I wrap 4 sweet potatoes in foil, bake for 4 hours at 400F.  They get really sticky and caramelize a bit.  Seperate flesh from skin and in the mash they go.  I usually bake the night before.

Answer (score 0):

Google tells me that (boiled) pumpkin is about 6% carbohydrates (1% protein, and not much else other than water) Barley is about 73% carbohydrates.

So my back of the envelope maths says that your normal mash is about 20% carbs)

The back of the envelope goes on to say:

If you put in one quart of mashed boiled pumpkin, put in one quart **less** water and 1/4 pounds **less** grain. Assuming that does not make the beer mash too gluggy.

However your YMMV

I will go home and calculate this properly tonight.